# Changing Default Text In CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I want change default text in CKEditor. If i can use PHP it would be simple. But i've use Jquery. So how can i change default text with using Jquery in CKEditor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I understand it to be that you are wanting to change the text in the content area of the editor. If so, you can check this support page out on the ckeditor.com site.

[ckEditor jQuery adapter](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter)

This requires an extra script to be added to your page, which enables a cleaner integration with jQuery.

To get/set the text inside the editor using jQuery, simply do this:

```
// Get the editor data.
var data = $( 'textarea.editor' ).val();
// Set the editor data.
$( 'textarea.editor' ).val( 'my new content' );
```

Comment: Well, it works. But i want to use ajax. Like this :
`$.post('evir.php',{dhic : degeer},
function(ajaxCevap4){      $("#editor1").val(ajaxCevap4);
}
);`

If i use like that the textarea'll have a value. But it can't see by user.